# Is it possible to use SplEnum in php 5.2.6?

Tags: php, spl

I tried to use class :

```
abstract class my_abstractEnum extends SplEnum {
...
}
```

and

```
class my_categoryEnum extends my_abstractEnum {
...
}
```

and I have :

> Fatal error: Class 'SplEnum' not found

I work on PHP 5.2.6.
SplEnum is for php > 5.3 ? I don't see so in the documentation ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[SplTypes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl-types.php) is an experimental [PECL Extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl-types.installation.php). You have to install it with `pecl install SPL_Types` from the command line. There is no DLL for windows, so you are limited to Linux (or have to build your own).

An alternative in userland can be found in http://www.whitewashing.de/2009/08/31/enums-in-php.html

Comment: So I'll try to do develop the same methods of SplEnum on my abstract class. Thanks !

Comment: Thats great for windows users :/