# SplEnum does not autoload in apache — works in CLI

Tags: php, autoload, spl

I'm having trouble autoloading a class I've written that extends SplEnum. I have successfully installed Spl_Types.

Strangely, the class autoloads fine when run via the CLI. I run into problems when running the scripts through apache, however.

The class is defined as follows:

```
<?php
namespace base\main\domain;
use SplEnum;
/**
 * Represents a colour.
 *
 **/
class Colour extends SplEnum {
...
```

Running this:

```
spl_autoload_register(array($autoLoader, 'autoLoad'));
spl_autoload_register('spl_autoload');
$colour = new base\main\domain\Colour(base\main\domain\Colour::BLACK);
```

Gives:

> Fatal error: Class 'SplEnum' not found in [...] Colour.php on line 8

I've run `phpinfo()` through apache and checked that the php.ini file listed includes the spl_types extension, but still no joy.

I'd greatly appreciate any help you could offer with this.

Thanks,

Ross

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846395/is-it-possible-to-use-splenum-in-php-5-2-6

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the other issue. As I said above, I have successfully installed SPL_Types, and I'm able to load the class in other circumstances. This problem relates to the differences in autoloading between CLI and Apache.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem, but it seems that a simple `service httpd restart` was needed.

SPL_TYPES used from https://github.com/davidcoallier/SPL_Types

Compiled with:

```
tar xvf SPL_Types-0.3.1.tgz
cd SPL_Types-0.3.1
phpize
./configure
make
make test
make install

echo -e "; Enable spl_types extension module\nextension=spl_types.so" > /etc/php.d/spl_types.ini
service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
class Colour extends \SplEnum {
```

Comment: I have now. No joy, I'm afraid.