# Using Enum classes in Laravel 5 project

Tags: php, enums, namespaces, laravel-5, psr-4

I want to use some enum classes in my laravel 5 app.
They are modeled after this PHP man page example: http://php.net/manual/en/class.splenum.php

The file app\Enums.php looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace MyApp\Enums;
class ItemStates extends SplEnum 
{
    const __default = self::Active;

    const Active = 1;
    const Pending = 2;
}

class ItemVisibility extends SplEnum
{
    const __default = self::Community;

    const Community = 1;
    const Personal = 2;
}
```

I want to use these from a controller. 
I put a use statement at the top of my controller:

```
use MyApp\Enums;
```

When I try to use the class like this:

```
if ($category['Family'] == CategoryFamily::General)
```

I get an error:
Class 'MyApp\Http\Controllers\Quiz\CategoryFamily' not found

I have run compose dump-autoload in case that matters.

How can I use my Enum classes from inside controllers (multiple controllers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but Laravel uses a [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) compliant autoloader. In the documentation of psr-4 it is mentioned:

> The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in .php. The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.

You can check if it uses this standard in your `composer.json` file to be sure:

```
"psr-4": {
    "MyApp\\": "app/"
}
```

This means it won't be able to find your class. I suggest you put each class into a separate file with the same name as the class and put that in a MyApp\Enum namespace for example.

The other options you have are to include your app using the `psr-0` standard in your `composer.json`, or to manually include your Enum file wherever you want it.

***UPDATE***

Once you've done this, you should be able to use SplEnum by putting `use SplEnum;` under the `namespace ..` in top of your file, if and only when you have SplTypes installed. If you're on Windows or do not want to install this [PECL Extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl-types.installation.php), then I suggest this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/254543/2433843 with an elegant solution.

Comment: I am new to laravel. I was wondering if putting each one in its own file was the answer, but it seemed it would be more convenient to keep them in a single file as they are just a few lines each.

Comment: I put the class in its own file, now I have a different error - Class MyApp\SplEnum not found.

Comment: It is looking for it in the namespace. Make it \SplEnum or put use SplEnum in the top of the file under the namespace

Comment: That would probably be it however I think perhaps I do not have spl_types installed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846395/is-it-possible-to-use-splenum-in-php-5-2-6 that might be the problem? Running XAMPP on Windows. Can you recommend another way I can implement similar functionality?

Comment: Yes you are correct, I do not think it is currently supported in Windows (even if that post is 4 years old; it's still not standard). The SplEnum class lacks features compared to the Enum implementation in other languages though. This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/254543/2433843 has two very good alternatives. One simple, for if your needs are simple. and one more elaboratefor if you need validation. You could put the base Enum in a Helper namespace for example. Updated answer for people who don't read comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to import the enum class :

```
namespace MyApp\Enums;
use SplEnum; // specify correct path if needed
```